# Fail to convert to internal representation (oracle.sql.ARRAY)

Tags: java, oracle12c

I want to convert my `Object[] Array` in `oracle.sql.ARRAY`, so I can insert it into my Oracle database (12c).

```
public class Datatransfer{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{

    Connection accessConn = null;
    Connection oracleConn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String mySelectSQL = "Select * from Supplier";

    try{
        oracleConn = DBConnection.connOracle();
        accessConn = DBConnection.connAccess();
        stmt = accessConn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(mySelectSQL);

        while(rs.next()){
           do_something...

           Object[] addressArray = {rs.getString("Street"),
                                   rs.getString("Location"),
                                   rs.getString("Region"),
                                   rs.getString("Postcode"),
                                   rs.getString("Country")};
           oracle.sql.ARRAY myAddressArray =
                        ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection)oracleConn).
                        createARRAY("ADDRESS_ARRAY", addressArray);

        do_something...

    }
    catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e)
    {e.printStrackTrace();}
    finally{
      Close_all_Connection ...
    }
}
```

At this point I get the following SQLException:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation: 49 Gilbert St.
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatum(OracleTypeADT.java:339)
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeADT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeADT.java:372)
at oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeUPT.toDatumArray(OracleTypeUPT.java:110)
at oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.toOracleArray(ArrayDescriptor.java:1238)
at oracle.sql.ARRAY.<init>(ARRAY.java:103)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.createARRAY
(PhysicalConnection.java:8649)
at nsd.datatrans.Datatransfer.main(Datatransfer.java:64)
```

So what can I do?

Comment: Isn't it deprecated? https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/ARRAY.html

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963472/java-sql-sqlexception-fail-to-convert-to-internal-representation

Comment: Also please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055361/java-sql-sqlexception-fail-to-convert-to-internal-representation-while-passing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java

Comment: The function `createARRAY()` still works for me. I used this function many times in my code.

Comment: Maybe the type `ADDRESS_ARRAY` doesn't exist in your database. See [Creating ARRAY Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/oraarr.htm#JJDBC28595)

Comment: How is your `ADRESS_ARRAY` [sic] type defined?  I can reproduce that error message and stacktrace if I declare `ADRESS_ARRAY` as a table of some other `OBJECT` type, but of course that's no guarantee that you've done exactly this.

Comment: First I created a type called `Address_Type`:
`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Adress_Type
AS
  OBJECT
  (
    Street VARCHAR2 (60) ,
    Location    VARCHAR2 (10) ,
    Region    VARCHAR2 (15) ,
    Postcode VARCHAR2 (15) ,
    Country   VARCHAR2 (15) ) NOT FINAL ;`
Then I created an Array-Type called `Address_Array`:
`create or replace TYPE Adress_Array IS VARRAY ( 10 ) OF Adress_Type ;`

The Address_Array should be stored in my table `Supplier`.

Comment: I solved the problem. I created a java class `AddressTyp.java` and set the attributes. Then i passed the class as object in `Object[] Array`. Now it works for me.